# Does python-bitcoinlib and the Bitcoin Core functional test framework share code? Were changes ever pushed down/upstream?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, python, functional-test, python-bitcoinlib

Does [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) and the Bitcoin Core [functional test framework](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/test/functional/test_framework) share code? Were changes ever pushed down/upstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[script.py](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/functional/test_framework/script.py) of the Bitcoin Core functional test framework contains a comment that it was initially modified from python-bitcoinlib.

There doesn't appear to have been any code sharing beyond that and certainly not any later changes pushed up/downstream.

I asked Kanzure (previous maintainer of python-bitcoinlib) on IRC about it and he said:

> python-bitcoinlib is forked from a thing that was itself incorporated into bitcoin core's functional test framework or the thing it was forked from was from code in the bitcoin core repository, i forget the lineage exactly but python-bitcoinlib came later